# Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-2

I am getting build error when run with maven. below is the error snippet.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/day/jcr/vault/maven-vault-plugin/0.0.10/maven-vault-plugin-0.0.10.pom
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:115)
        ... 30 more
[DEBUG] Using Wagon implementation lightweight from default mapping for protocol http
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.day.jcr.vault:maven-vault-plugin:pom:0.0.10' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[DEBUG] Trying repository adobe-public
[DEBUG] Using Wagon implementation lightweight from default mapping for protocol http
[DEBUG] Checking for pre-existing User-Agent configuration.
[DEBUG] Adding User-Agent configuration.
[DEBUG] Connecting to repository: 'adobe-public' with url: 'http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'.
Downloading: http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public//com/day/jcr/vault/maven-vault-plugin/0.0.10/maven-vault-plugin-0.0.10.pom
[DEBUG] attempting to create parent directories for destination: maven-vault-plugin-0.0.10.pom.tmp
178b downloaded  (maven-vault-plugin-0.0.10.pom)
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '81ffbd1712afe8cdf138b570c0fc9934742c33c1'; remote = '<html>
<head><title>301' - RETRYING
Downloading: http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public//com/day/jcr/vault/maven-vault-plugin/0.0.10/maven-vault-plugin-0.0.10.pom
[DEBUG] attempting to create parent directories for destination: maven-vault-plugin-0.0.10.pom.tmp
178b downloaded  (maven-vault-plugin-0.0.10.pom)
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '81ffbd1712afe8cdf138b570c0fc9934742c33c1'; remote = '<html>
<head><title>301' - IGNORING
[DEBUG] Using Wagon implementation lightweight from default mapping for protocol http
[DEBUG]   Artifact resolved
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: com.day.jcr.vault:maven-vault-plugin
POM Location: C:\Users\username\.m2\repository\com\day\jcr\vault\maven-vault-plugin\0.0.10\maven-vault-plugin-0.0.10.pom

Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project com.day.jcr.vault:maven-vault-plugin at C:\Users\username\.m2\repository\com\day\jcr\vault\maven-vault-plugi
n\0.0.10\maven-vault-plugin-0.0.10.pom


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Unable to build project for plugin 'com.day.jcr.vault:maven-vault-plugin': Not a v4.0.0 POM. f
or project com.day.jcr.vault:maven-vault-plugin at C:\Users\username\.m2\repository\com\day\jcr\vault\maven-vault-plugin\0.0.10\maven-vault-plugin
-0.0.10.pom
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.loadPluginFully(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1599)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.findArtifactTypeHandlersInPlugins(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1468)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.findExtensions(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:222)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:178)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
```

I have added maven repo then adobe repo. Intially build try to find vault plugin through maven repo, which cause error FNF, then tried adobe repo. Vault plugin is present on adobe repo, but its download only POM with 301 message.

Any thoughts.

pom snippet :

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-central</id>
            <name>Maven2</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>adobe-public</id>
            <name>Adobe</name>
            <url>https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

After changing to https, fall back not happen to adobe. Below is the error :

```
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/day/jcr/vault/maven-vault-plugin/0.0.10/maven-vault-plugin-0.0.10.jar
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:115)
    ... 27 more
[DEBUG] Using Wagon implementation lightweight from default mapping for protocol http
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.day.jcr.vault:maven-vault-plugin:maven-plugin:0.0.10' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Plugin could not be found - check that the goal name is correct: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
```

Comment: Looks like you are beding a corporate proxy or firewall...where are not allowed to go through...

Comment: @khmarbaise : there is no jar to download at  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/day/jcr/vault/maven-vault-plugin/0.0.10/maven-vault-plugin-0.0.10.jar . I wonder whay fallback didn't moved to adobe repo.

Answer (score 2):

You request an `http` URL and get back a 301 redirect to an `https` URL. Such redirects between schemes is not followed by default, because of security risks. When the POM is requested only the 301 redirect HTML page is retrieved which has `81ffbd1712afe8cdf138b570c0fc9934742c33c1` as SHA1 checksum. Then the POM URL + `.sha1` is retrieved which should have the checksum of the POM in its first line and they are compared. Here again you onyl get the 301 redirect page, so `81ffbd1712afe8cdf138b570c0fc9934742c33c1` is compared against `'<html>\n<head><title>301'` which of course does not match.

Configure the `https` URL instead for the Adobe repo directly and it should work just fine.